# The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in a reasonable time in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a line of code that sets the background of Text to an Image that is fetched by finding the first three letters of the string. For some reason this won't run and keeps giving me the error above. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

There are a lot of images that need to be set as the backgrounds for multiple different pieces of text. I believe I have the right idea by using the prefix of the string, but it seems like Xcode is having difficulty/won't run this.

Pretty sure this specific line is giving me issues, but would love some feedback.
`.background(Image(colorOption.prefix(3)).resizable())`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ColorView: View {
    // @ObservedObject var survey = Survey()
    @ObservedObject var api = ColorAPIRequest(survey: DataStore.instance.currentSurvey!)
    @State var showingConfirmation = true
    @State var showingColorView = false
    @State var tempSelection = ""


    @EnvironmentObject var survey: Survey

    //@EnvironmentObject var api: APIRequest

    var colorOptionsGrid: [[String]] {
        var result: [[String]] = [[]]
        let optionsPerRow = 4
        api.colorOptions.dropFirst().forEach { colorOption in
            if result.last!.count == optionsPerRow { result.append([]) }
            result[result.count - 1].append(colorOption)
        }
        return result
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Select Tape Color")
                .font(.system(size:70))
                .bold()
                .padding(.top, 20)

            NavigationLink("", destination: LengthView(), isActive: $showingColorView)

            HStack {

                List {
                    ForEach(colorOptionsGrid, id: \.self) { colorOptionRow in
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(colorOptionRow, id: \.self) { colorOption in

                                Button(action: {

                                    // self.survey.length = lengthOption
                                    self.tempSelection = colorOption
                                    self.showingConfirmation = false

                                }

                                ) {


                                    ZStack {
                                        Color.clear
                                        Text(colorOption.prefix(3))
                                            .font(.title)
                                            .foregroundColor(self.tempSelection == colorOption ? Color.white : Color.black)
                                            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                                            .background(Image(colorOption.prefix(3)).resizable())
                                     //Image(colorOption.prefix(3)).resizable()
                                    }

                                }.listRowBackground(self.tempSelection == colorOption ? Color.pink : Color.white)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }
                        }


                    }

                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            }


            Button(action: {
                self.survey.color = self.tempSelection
                self.showingColorView = true
                self.showingConfirmation = true

            }) {
                Text("Press to confirm \(tempSelection)")
                    .bold()
                    .padding(50)
                    .background(Color.pink)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(size:40))
                    .cornerRadius(90)
            }.isHidden(showingConfirmation)
                .padding(.bottom, 50)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler actually gives a fairly decent suggestion when it tells you to break the expression up. The simplest you can do is extract the background image into a separate function like this:

```
func backgroundImage(for colorOption: String) -> some View {
    Image(String(colorOption.prefix(3))).resizable()
}
```

and then replace the call to

```
.background(Image(colorOption.prefix(3)).resizable())
```

with

```
.background(self.backgroundImage(for: colorOption))
```

Also note that I wrapped `colorOption.prefix(3)` in a `String` constructor, simply because `.prefix(_:)` returns a `Substring`, but the `Image(_:)` constructor requires a String.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately I tried replacing it and I still get the same error.

Comment: Either way, I suggest you continue what I suggested in the original post, break the code up into more smaller parts, either as functions or computed properties, or separate `View` structs